# Why does PHP script fail to insert into MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, post

I am trying to figure out why an error occurs when my PHP script tries to insert data into a MySQL database.

I am working on a small form that collects data, and then in PHP I submit it into my SQL database. When I submit it, I get a blank page and nothing is inserted, I have added an echo to display if the insert fails, which it is.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("host", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db") or die(mysql_error());

$name=$_POST['repname'];
$replace=$_POST['replace'];
$reg=$_POST['reg'];
info=$_POST['info'];

if($name == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Rep name missing.';
    $errflag = true;
}

if($replace == '') {
$errmsg_arr[] = 'Please fill out all the forms.';
$errflag = true;
}
if($reg == '') {
$errmsg_arr[] = 'Please fill out all the forms.';
$errflag = true;
}
if($info == '') {
$errmsg_arr[] = 'Please add some other information about your rep.';
$errflag = true;
}


if(!mysql_query("INSERT INTO reps (name, replace, reg, boxinfo) VALUES          
('".$name."','".$replace."','".$reg."','".$info."')"))   
{ 
 echo 'failed'; 
} 
else 
{ 
 echo 'inserted'; 
}

?>
```

Comment: You are missing a `$` before ---> (info) variable `info=$_POST['info'];`

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran, post that as an answer before someone else does :D

Comment: Was just going to say that too.

Comment: Plus you're open to SQL injection. Read this => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: But he didn't mention any syntax errors so i am still wondering ^_^

Comment: If the OP said to put it as an answer, then we can assume it's correct ;-) @ShankarDamodaran

Comment: @Fred-ii- but the OP didn't say that.

Comment: LOL, yes I just noticed that @Jessica my bad ;-)

Comment: Scratch that @ShankarDamodaran ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Beside [Shankar's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828034/mysql-database-not-inserting#comment31235058_20828034) `replace` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) use backticks.

```
INSERT INTO reps (name, `replace`, reg, boxinfo)
```

Comment: LOL! It's something I like to do, in order to put emphasis and clarification ;-) @Mihai